# Machine Learning using R linear regression

Tags: r, machine-learning

I used R for machine learning code. My project scenario as mentioned below.
I used MongoDB for database storage. In mongo db I had one collection in that collection every 5 min. one new document added. The collection description as below.

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("521c980624c8600645ad23c8"),
"TimeStamp" : 1377605638752,
"cpuUsed" : -356962527,
"memory" : 2057344858,
"hostId" : "200.2.2.2"
 }
```

Now my problem is that using above documents I want to predict next 5 min or 10 min or 24 hrs. cpuUsed and memory values. For that I write R code as below

```
library('RMongo')
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect('dbname')
query <- dbGetQuery(mg1,'test',"{'hostId' : '200.2.2.2'}")
data1 <- query[]
cpu <- query$cpuUtilization
memory <- query$memory
new <- data.frame(data=1377678051) # set timestamp for calculating results
predict(lm(cpu ~   data1$memory + data1$Date ), new, interval="confidence")
```

But, when I was execute above code it shows me following output

```
           fit        lwr       upr
    1    427815904  -37534223 893166030
    2   -110791661 -368195697 146612374
    3    137889445 -135982781 411761671
    4   -165891990 -445886859 114102880
    .
    .
    .
    n
```

Using this output I don't know which cpuUsed value used for predicting values.
If any one knows please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, in above code I was change R code as below `code`              library('RMongo')
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect('dbname'')
query <- dbGetQuery(mg1,'final',"{'hostId' : '100.1.1.1'}")
date <- query$Date
memory <- query$memory
cpu <- query$cpuUtilization
res <- lm(cbind(memory,cpu) ~ date-1)
new <- data.frame(date=1377843220) # date passed in timestamp      
predict(res,new) it gives me answer but, I don't know this method good or not to predicting results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `newdata` parameter of predict needs to contain the variables used in the fit:

`new <- data.frame(memory = 1377678051, Date=as.Date("2013-08-28))`

Only then it is actually used for prediction, otherwise you get the fitted values.

You can then `cbind` the predicted values with `new`.

Comment: Hi I used your suggestion in my code and It work but problem is that my query contains 101 records and when I was run code it shows warning  1: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 101 rows 
2: In predict.lm(lm(cpu ~ data1$memory + data1$Date), new, interval = "confidence") :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading 
and results shows all 101 records with fit lwr upr values but, I want only single value for cpu which fitted for my output so I was predicted that next coming cpuUsed value.