# MongoDB and R Machine Learning

Tags: mongodb, r

I used following code for calculating next cpuused and memory used using given timestamp.

```
    library('RMongo')
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect('dbname')
query <- dbGetQuery(mg1,'collectionname',"{'hostId' : '600.6.6.6'}")
date <- query$Date
memory <- query$memory
cpu <- query$cpuUtilization
res <- lm(cbind(memory,cpu) ~ date-1)
new <- data.frame(date=1377843220)
predict(res,new)
```

And my mongo structure was

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52204f5b24c8cbf03ca16f8e"),
"Date" : 1377849179,
"cpuUtilization" : 31641,
"memory" : 20623801,
"hostId" : "600.6.6.6"
}
```

Above R ML code shows me next prediction cpuuesd and memory values please tell me my code goes wrong or right?

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting a review of code.

Comment: It is only a linear model: the predicted cpu usage will either regularly increase, or regularly decrease -- if it decreases, it will eventually become become negative. In addition, you removed the intercept. Have you plotted your data to check if those assumptions were reasonable? Since you mention "machine learning", have you checked the forecasts on a validation set, and compared them with a simpler model (e.g., use the last value as a forecast)?

Comment: Hi Vincent I am beginner in R language and ML so I don't know how to use validate and forecast data. I tried from myself searching on INTERNET and do myself. Same problem I listed in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484025/machine-learning-using-r-linear-regression here so please tell me what is best approach to finding prediction results using R and ML.